# Batch alignment of inconsistently named Fastq files

Tags: read-mapping, fastq, shell

I have numerous gzip-compressed paired-end Fastq files with ChIP-seq data that I would like to align with bowtie2. I confirmed that bowtie2 takes `.gz` files, although I do see this warning when I run for two samples:

> Warning: gzbuffer added in zlib v1.2.3.5. Unable to change buffer size
>   from default of 8192.

My files are named like so.

```
10_S10_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  12_S12_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  2_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz  4_S4_L001_R1_001.fastq-003.gz  6_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq-002.gz  8_S8_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  
10_S10_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz  12_S12_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz  2_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz  4_S4_L001_R2_001.fastq-002.gz  6_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq-003.gz  8_S8_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz  
11_S11_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz    3_S3_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz  5_S5_L001_R1_001.fastq-002.gz  7_S7_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz      9_S9_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
11_S11_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz  1_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz    3_S3_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz  5_S5_L001_R2_001.fastq-003.gz  7_S7_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz      9_S9_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

The bash commands I tried are below. When I run this test command:

```
for i in $(ls *.fastq*.gz | grep -v 6 | rev | cut -c 16- | rev | uniq); do 
    echo $i; 
done
```

...I get this output.

```
12_S12_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  12_S12_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

When I run this:

```
for i in $(ls *.fastq*.gz | rev | cut -c 16- | rev | uniq); do 
    echo $i 
    bowtie2 -q -p20 -x /run/media/punit/data1/BowtieIndex/hg38 -1 ${i}R1_001.fastq.gz -2 ${i}R2_001.fastq.gz | samtools view -bS - >${i%}.bam
done
```

I do see one BAM for my paired end files. But as I see the second set of files which are named:

```
6_S6_L001_R1_001.fastq-002.gz  6_S6_L001_R2_001.fastq-003.gz
```

if I run the same script over them, I would get an error as the loop can't read the paired end file.

So the tedious way is I can make a separate folder for these sets of data with `fastq-002.gz` and `fastq-003.gz` and can run the script by tweaking the `cut` parameter.

But I would like to know what is the programmatic way of resolving the issue.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to use something like `snakeMake` rather than making a shell script. It's both much easier to ensure the proper files are paired and it scales to use in clusters and the cloud.

Comment: Can't you just rename the files?

Comment: @terdon that's how our collaborator gave us and i dont want to mess up with the file name yes i can if i dont find any other way..

Comment: " strongly encourage you to use something like snakeMake rather than making a shell script. It's both much easier to ensure the proper files are paired and it scales to use in clusters and the cloud." i read a bit about it never tried it , i need to learn and give it a try

Comment: It's good practice to treat files from collaborators as read-only, so not changing the filenames is a good idea. But if the files are inconsistently named, it's a very good idea to create consistently named symlinks to those files. Well organized filenames and directory structures will make it SO NICE AND EASY to automate batch data processing.

Comment: yes i did that finally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple approach, but one which will work with the names you show, is to remove any occurrence of `00N` (where `N` is any number) from right before the `.gz`. To do so, edit your script to:

```
for i in $(ls *.fastq*.gz | sed 's/00[0-9]\.gz/.gz/' | rev | cut -c 16- | rev | uniq); do 
  bowtie2 -q -p20 -x /run/media/punit/data1/BowtieIndex/hg38 \
    -1 ${i}R1_001.fastq.gz \
    -2 ${i}R2_001.fastq.gz | 
        samtools view -bS - >${i%}.bam"
done
```